# How will I handle multiple windows in my code?

Tags: java, selenium, visual-studio-code, testng

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTdsv.png)java

```
List<WebElement> group = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@ng-repeat='employeeGroup in employeeGroups']"));
for (int k = 0; k < group.size(); k++) {
        if (group.get(k).getText().toLowerCase().startsWith(shuttleObj.getGroupName().toLowerCase())) {
            group.get(k)
                    .findElement(
                            By.xpath("//body//div[" + (k + 2) + "]//li[1]/ul/a/i"))
                    .click();
            Thread.sleep(500);

            String firstparent = driver.getWindowHandle();
            for (String firstchild : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
                driver.switchTo().window(firstchild);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                driver.findElement(By.xpath(props.getProperty("thirdEmployee"))).click();
                Thread.sleep(200);
                driver.findElement(By.xpath(props.getProperty("fourthEmployee"))).click();
                Thread.sleep(200);
                driver.findElement(By.xpath(props.getProperty("selectedEmployeeTab"))).click();
                Thread.sleep(200);
            }

            driver.switchTo().window(firstparent);
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            group.get(k).findElement(By.xpath("//body//div[" + (k + 2) + "]//li[2]/ul/a/i")).click();
            String secondparent = driver.getWindowHandle();
            for (String secondchild : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
                driver.switchTo().window(secondchild);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                driver.findElement(By.xpath(props.getProperty("thirdEmployee"))).click();
                Thread.sleep(200);
                driver.findElement(By.xpath(props.getProperty("fourthEmployee"))).click();
                Thread.sleep(200);
                driver.findElement(By.xpath(props.getProperty("selectedEmployeeTab"))).click();
                Thread.sleep(200);
                driver.switchTo().window(secondparent);
            }
        }
```

I amup able to click first child but I can't be able to click second child.

This is giving the error is:  Message:
`stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document`

Comment: Try adding `driver.switchTo().defaultContent();` before switching to `secondparent` in the `secondchild` loop (last but one line)

Comment: It's working. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

you have to switch to base page before switching to the second page in the loop, as shown in the below code.

```
for (String secondchild : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
                driver.switchTo().window(secondchild);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                driver.findElement(By.xpath(props.getProperty("thirdEmployee"))).click();
                Thread.sleep(200);
                driver.findElement(By.xpath(props.getProperty("fourthEmployee"))).click();
                Thread.sleep(200);
                driver.findElement(By.xpath(props.getProperty("selectedEmployeeTab"))).click();
                Thread.sleep(200);
                driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
                driver.switchTo().window(secondparent);
            }
```

Comment: I am doing the same thing but it's giving me the error

Error: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

Comment: Try adding Expected Conditions.

Comment: I have shared the screen shot. I have to click the + icon of chembur. But I am not able to click it.

Comment: If this answer or the comment solves the issue please accept/update the answer to mark this question solved